# Delphi: Right aligned panel flickers upon resizing form

Tags: delphi, resize, drawing, flicker

it should be simple but I don't find how to do it.

I create a form with a right aligned panel that I color in blue for example.

If I grab my forms left edge and resize it back and forth horizontally quickly, I would like the right panel not to move or flicker. As its position is unchanged, there is no reason why it should not stay completely steady. Does anybody know a simple trick to solve this apparently simple problem?

Thanks

Comment: Try setting `DoubleBuffered := True` in the form constructor.

Comment: Actually this is not a flicker problem, it's an alignment problem. That other question won't help here.

Comment: I did set doubleBuffered to TRUE. I also tried to do the alignment myself by positioning the right panel in the FormResize method. No luck.

Comment: Presumably the real app has a panel with controls in rather than just the colour blue?

Comment: Yes the real app has a client aligned listview in the panel. But I thought I should try to solve the simplest case first. :-)

Answer (score 7):

This is just a fact of life with Windows GUI apps. You can see the same effect in a WinForms app and indeed even in mainstream Windows apps. For example, open an Explorer window and do exactly the same operation, resize by grabbing the left hand edge of the window. You will see exactly the same effect. You can see the same effect by resizing from any edge. Word and Excel behave in the same way.

My guess is that Windows repaints in the sizing loop before it sends the resizing message that allows the app to realign its controls.

Comment: You may be right but I find it difficult to accept. In my opinion, even if it is not always easy to achieve, we should always try to avoid repainting a portion of a window when it is unnecessary. In the simple case that I described, the only portion that should be repainted is the portion that is affected by the resizing. Hence the right panel should stay steady.

Comment: If the window manager is doing this then you simply are out of luck. Would be worth experimenting with XP which renders quit differently.